# the REFERENCES privilege is only about creating a foreign key constraint? Practical use cases?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, permissions, foreign-key, referential-integrity

Today I learned about `GRANT REFERENCES`. In years of SQL admin and dev work I never heard about it and never had issues with it.

quote from [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  / GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

> REFERENCES    Enable foreign key creation. Levels: Global, database,
>   table, column.

quote from [PostgreSQL 9.6 / GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html)

> REFERENCES To create a foreign key constraint, it is necessary to have
>   this privilege on both the referencing and referenced columns. The
>   privilege may be granted for all columns of a table, or just specific
>   columns.

is `GRANT REFERENCES` only about creating a foreign key constraint? In what business case does it make sense to forbid creating a foreign key constraint (but allow to create tables)? Can you give me real world examples?

Comment: One use case for this is if you have a user with read-only access to a database, and they need to create a foreign key to reference that read-only data *from a different database* on which they have full write access. In this case, it would be necessary to give the user REFERENCES permission on the relevant table in the read-only database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the ability to create a foreign key constraint, you are actually getting permission to check for the existence/non-existence of a certain value in a certain column (or set of columns) of a table. You may *not* have the privilege to `SELECT` the whole list of values in this column, but you can already *know something* about them. You could try to insert values on the *referencing* table. The ones that are allowed, you already know exist in the *referenced* table.

If you should *know absolutely nothing* about those values, you cannot be granted the privilege to make a `foreign key constraint` on the column.

Add to that the considerations pointed out by @Erwin, WRT to being able to *prevent* deletes from the *referenced* tables.

Answer (score 6):

What joanolo describes is a valid consideration. A user can achieve partial `SELECT` privileges on the referenced table if (s)he is allowed to create a FK reference.

More importantly, a user that can create an FK reference to a table can effectively also **prevent deletion of rows and update of key columns**. Rows with a FK reference to it are protected that way (unless `CASCADE` has been defined for `DELETE` and `UPDATE`. [The Postgres manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

> Restricting and cascading deletes are the two most common options.
>   `RESTRICT` prevents deletion of a referenced row. `NO ACTION` means that
>   if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an
>   error is raised; this is the default behavior if you do not specify anything.

Answer (score 3):

To extend on Erwin's answer, there's a third case why the creation of foreign key constraints may require special permissions:

- a foreign key grants users of the table the ability to test for existence of rows in the referenced table
- a foreign key with `RESTRICT` or `NO ACTION` rules prevents users of the referenced table from updating or deleting referenced row, and gives them the ability to test for the existence of referencing rows
- a foreign key with `CASCADE` or `SET NULL`/`DEFAULT` rules also **grants users of the referenced table the ability to update or delete rows in the referencing table**

I have not found this anywhere in the Postgres documentation, but only mentioned in passing on the mailing list [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMsGm5e1m-shu-JKFQwg3SkPhc%2BNXwf5J-5BPzWcan1Mb%2B1JfA%40mail.gmail.com)

> When a foreign key reference delete cascades, I can cause records to
> disappear from a referencing table even if I don't have delete permission
> on that table.

and [there](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/987.1496697317%40sss.pgh.pa.us)

> FK CASCADE queries are run as the owner of the table in question.

This perhaps surprising behaviour is also topic of [this MySQL bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34120).

IBM states in their [Informix documentation](https://informix.hcldoc.com/12.10/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_0677.htm)

> To have DELETE actions cascade to a table that has a referential constraint on a parent table, you need the Delete privilege only on the parent table that you reference in the DELETE statement.